# Configuration file default.doxygen for Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, doxygen

I am trying to install doxygen plugin for visual studio 2010 in windows. Followed the steps given in this article

[Minutes-to-document-your-code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3528/Minutes-to-document-your-code)

But when I click on doxygen under windows it says configuration file default.doxygen not found.

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed one step in the guide where you should download and place mentioned file, but apparently, this file is missing in a guide. Place [an alternative file](http://studierstube.icg.tugraz.at/misc/sample_doxy_config.txt) to your project's folder and rename it to "default.doxygen".

Comment: no i have added this file in the project directory.

Comment: Have you tried running from [command line](https://www.star.bnl.gov/public/comp/sofi/doxygen/starting.html#step2) with specifying configuration file?

Comment: And when doxygen called from command line like `doxygen %path-to-file%` it still shows error?

Comment: So, is it running then? Or just silently fails?

Comment: No its running. By using doxygen GUI i am able to view the documents in chrome but when i try with Visual Studio 2010 under tools options it give me error configuration file not found. What is the exact location where i need to place doxygen.defualt file

Comment: When you adding a tool to Visual Studio you can specify arguments with which run the program. For example in a guide that you're using it's `$(WkspDir)\default.doxygen`. if you already have this replace `WkspDir` with `SolutionDir` and try again.